# DocumentClass-Independent Table of Contents (eToC)

Tags: tocloft, minitoc, etoc

I want to create a local table of contents, and am currently using etoc. I noticed that the formatting is largely dependent of the documentclass.
Below is a screenshot for the article document class result of `\localtableofcontents.`
[image: Article document class etoc]

and the `\localtableofcontents` for the report documentclass [image]

My LaTeX needs to be written in the article document class but I would really to make the formatting of the local toc to match the report document class. More specifically the smaller gaps between lines and the ........ before page numbers.

I've scanned through the [documentation for etoc](https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/etoc/etoc.pdf) and it's filled with complex macros that I'm having difficulty manipulating to get the desired result.

Here's a MWE

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoc}

\title{Report Doc Class}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

    \localtableofcontents

     \section{first section (of report doc class)}

     \section{second section}

     \section{third section}
\end{document}
```

I'm also curious if there's any strong preferences for etoc vs tocloft vs minitoc etc. for local table of contents. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `tocloft` package. I have taken your MWE, for which thanks, changed it to the `article` class and added `tocloft` code to tweak the local ToC to what you say you want.

**EDIT** I have changed the MWE to unbold the ToC entries as asked for in a commment by the OP. I have not changed the graphic to match which shows the original bold entries.

```
% etocprob2.tex  SE 622703

\documentclass{article} %\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}  % must be before etoc package
\renewcommand{\cftsecdotsep}{\cftdotsep} % add dots to section entries
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0pt} % no extra vertical space between section entries
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{} % normal (non-bold) font for section entries
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{} % normal font for section pages

\usepackage{etoc}

%\title{Report Doc Class}
\title{Article Doc Class}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

%\tableofcontents

   \localtableofcontents

     \section{first section (of article doc class)}

     \section{second section}

     \section{third section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this! So you suggest using the Tocloft package on top of the Etoc package, any reasons for this combination instead of say, minitoc etc.? Would you recommend that I use Tocloft for customizations and not Etoc directly then? :) Also is there a way to make the font not bold for the contents of the localToC as in the report documentclass?

Comment: You wanted to use `etoc` but did not understand the details. I showed you how to change the `etoc` output by using an additional package. Check my edited answer. `tocloft` was designed to modify the appearance of the normal class's ToC, LoF and LoT and also works with `etoc`. I have never used `minitoc` or `etoc`; the packages you use are up to you. I have no idea why you think that `etoc` results should be independent of the class.

Comment: "I have no idea why you think that etoc results should be independent of the class." literally never claimed that. I mentioned that I notice that they depend on the document class, never claimed that it should be otherwise. but thanks I guess